# NSUserDefaults and adding UIImages to an application via the web

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have an app that uses chat stickers. I would like to add more stickers to the app over time without having to make the user download an update. I understand that I can store data in NSUserDefaults so was wondering if it's possible to get an app to download images from a server to the NSDefaults? Say via parse or a similar service? Is this kind of thing allowed in an app? I read something in the developer guidelines that placeholders could not be used. Any advice on this would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do not store images in `NSUserDefaults`. Store the images in the Caches folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use parse the store all the images in a table in the parse file storage. Download the images using the Parse SDK. The downloaded images will be cached appropriately by the SDK so you won't need to handle the cache yourself.

You can read more about how to store files with Parse here: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files/iOS

Answer (score 0):

NSUserdefaults is not meant to store big files like images. It should only contain small amounts of data.

You will need to download the images and save them locally. To download the image to a file use [`NSURLDownload`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html).